# How to edit selected row of UITableView in DetaliView to update contents of selected cell (Core Data)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, uitableview

I am creating an app using Swift 3 that displays a tableview to the user.
[image of tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKe7U.png)

The user can add, delete, and edit each selected row in the table. I figured out how to segue to a detailed view of the cell. In the detail View I have two text fields that the user can edit to change the title and details of the selected row.
[image of detailView for selectedCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH7eV.png)

I am using a prepareForSegue method to change the title of the selected row by getting the text inputted in the detail view then saving permanetly--similar to how a contacts book works; you can press on a cell, go to detail view and edit attributes, save changes.

my prepare for segue method is not working and when I enter text in the textfield for the selectedCell it doesn't do anything..

here is my prepareforsegue method:

```
fun prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: UITableViewCell) {
    if segue.identifier == "details" {
    let path = self.placeTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let selectedCell = placeTable.cellForRow(at: path)! as UITableViewCell
    let cellText: String? = selectedCell.textLabel?.text
    let cellDetails: String? = selectedCell.detailTextLabel?.text

let dest:DetailViewController? = segue.destination as?    DetailViewController
    dest?.enterNewName.text = cellText
dest?.enterNewDescrip.text = cellDetails

NSLog("did select and the text is \(cellText)")
```

DetailViewController.swift:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var nameVar: NSString!

@IBOutlet weak var enterNewName: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var enterNewDescrip: UITextView!


@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
}


@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {


let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    appDelegate.saveContext()


    }


   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()


  }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }}
```

I would appreciate any advice that will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Don't pass strings; pass the NsManagedObject and then you can manipulate its properties directly in the detail view

Comment: thanks for the advice! I appreciate it!